# implementing BeanPostProcessor spring 5 + java 9

Tags: spring, interface, overriding

I'm writing my own `BeanPostProcessor` and so creating a class implementing BeanPostProcessor interface in eclipse Oxygen and java 9 infrastructure.

Now the question is - compiler is not allowing me to use @Override annotation for methods - `postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object,String)` and `postProcessAfterInitialization(Object,String)`. Why? And **Even if I do not provide implementation for these methods in my class**, I'm not getting compiler complaints which is against Interface rule. I mean I should get compiler error telling me that interface methods must be implemented. But not. Why? please guide me.

Answer (score 2):

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;

public class DisplayNameBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {
        System.out.println("Before "+bean.getClass() + "  " + beanName);
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {
        System.out.println("After "+bean.getClass() + "  " + beanName);
        return bean;
    }


}
```

The compiler will allow you to use @Override.

```
@Nullable
default Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    return bean;
}
```

In method definition we have the 'default' keyword introduced in Java 8 due to which it's not necessary for you to implement this method. In this case, Java has provided 'return bean;' as the body for this method.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the signature of e.g.`postProcessBeforeInitialization`

```
    @Nullable
    default Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }
```

You will notice that this method is defined in an interface but is already declared as **default** and thus has an implementation. So you do not need to override it.

Comment: Oh how big fool I am.. Could not notice the power of default methods in interfaces after java 8. It was not possible before jdk 8 I think. Am I correct ?

Comment: Correct. default methods were added in Java 8.

Comment: Correct. default methods were added in Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

I have same question, Now you do want to override the methods, I want to create my own bean processor so I override the two methods Now in the interface the parameters are @Nullable

So I can suppress the warning or add @NullAble annotations to my parameters of my methods.

You can override default methods.

I have Intellij and java9 with springboot-2 and I do annotate my methods with @override as you should be able to override non final method including default Interface methods.

`@Override public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(@Nullable final Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException`